# Why is the test "test_inputstream..." succeeding, shouldnt it be failing?

Tags: java, testing, java.util.scanner, inputstream, junit5

```
package com.skilldistillery.lordo.app;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class UITest {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    InputStream mockInputStream;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        // This will run once before any of the test methods in the class.
        mockInputStream = new MockInputStream();
        System.setIn(mockInputStream);
    }

    @Test
    void test_inputstream_fails_on_mismatch() {
        assertEquals("quiffdt", sc.nextLine());
    }

}
class MockGame implements CLIGame {
    @Override
    public void pushEvent(GameEvent event) {}
}

class MockInputStream extends InputStream {

    private byte[] inputBytes;
    private int position = 0;

    public MockInputStream() {
        String input = "quit" + System.lineSeparator();
        this.inputBytes = input.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (position < inputBytes.length) {
            return inputBytes[position++];
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Im really new to java, but i thought by setting my input stream to a custom one, i could mock the input stream. is this incorrect? Im trying to set up a mock for a project im working on. And i could be going about this completely wrong, im just not sure.

Comment: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` runs when the object is constructed. `init()` runs after that. At that point it is too late to reassign the scanner input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot reassign the "standard" input stream (i. e. your System's input) to your mock-implementation. However, you can create your own instance of a Scanner that uses your mock instead (of the "standard" input stream):

```
@Test
void test_inputstream_fails_on_mismatch() {
    sc = new Scanner(mockInputStream);
    assertEquals("quiffdt", sc.nextLine());
}
```

That test fails. Is that what you want?